# Golang OpenAPI generator wraps query parameters into an object while the Java counterpart does not

Tags: java, go, openapi, openapi-generator

So I'm using openAPI to generate API classes in Golang and Java. The way the generators of the respective languages interpret the yml file seems to be different.

Here is a part of the yml file:

```
parameters:
        - name: collectionName
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: filter_by
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
        - name: batch_size
          in: query 
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
```

And the generator for Golang generated the following structure:

```
type DeleteDocumentsParams struct {

    FilterBy string `json:"filter_by"`

    BatchSize int `json:"batch_size"`
}
```

while for Java, no such class was created. However if I wrap the `filter_by` and `batch_size` parameters within an object like this

```
  parameters:
    - name: collectionName
      in: path
      description: The name of the collection to delete documents from
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: deleteQueryParams
      in: query
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:      
          filter_by:
            type: string
          batch_size:
            type: integer
```

A DeleteQueryParams class gets created in Java. But in Golang the parameters are added to a nested structure like this

```
type DeleteDocumentsParams struct {
    DeleteQueryParams *struct {
        BatchSize *int    `json:"batch_size,omitempty"`
        FilterBy  *string `json:"filter_by,omitempty"`
    } `json:"deleteQueryParams,omitempty"`
}
```

Long story short, the Golang generator adds a layer of wrapping for the query parameters I specify while the Java generator does not. Is it possible to achieve an uniformity in this case. Or, is there any flags that I can use to enable or disable the object wrapping of parameters?

Comment: So I have tried to use [`openapi-generator`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) before. The code quality was not great and it was relatively difficult to use. After trying a few other options, I found this was the best generator for OpenAPI specifications: [`go-swagger`](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger). Here are some links to the documentation that are relevant to your issue for `go-swagger`: [models](https://goswagger.io/faq/faq_model.html) and [schema](https://goswagger.io/use/models/schemas.html). `go-swagger` only supports OpenAPI 2.0 AKA Swagger 2.0.